# Update MDC in Method

Tags: c#, nlog

Lets say you have Code using the Mapped Diagnostig Context with Using:

```
public string TransformTruTopsFABExport(string xmlFile) {
var xml = String.Empty;

using (NestedDiagnosticsContext.Push(Guid.NewGuid()))
using (MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("xmlFile", xmlFile))
using (MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("xml", xml))
{
    try
    {
        Logger.Info("Transformation started.");
        xml = Decorated.TransformTruTopsFABExport(xmlFile);
        MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("xml", xml); // Try to remove it
        Logger.Debug("Transformation done.");
        return xml;
    }
    finally
    {
        xml = null;
    }
}
```

}

How could i update the Variable "xml" and automatically mirror the update in the MDC without setting it from new?
After the Using, it will be removed from the stack automatically, but it seems like double code. Are there something like c pointers i could use?

Edit: Before you ask, i already try´d to use a DataClass like this:

```
    class Dataclass
{
    public string xml { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return xml;
    }
}

class Logicclass
{
    Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Logicclass");

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var dc = new Dataclass();

        using (MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("xml", dc))
        {
            try
            {
                logger.Info("before XML");
                dc.xml = "xmlcode";
                logger.Info("after XML");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, "ow noos!");
                throw;
            }
        }

        logger.Info("after using");
    }
}
```

And yes, it would update it. But that is not the answer i am looking for.

Edit:
Easiest solution for variables are immutable and reference would no work, is using StringBuilder for it. The to Update the StringBuilder Object is simple and here is a working solution with using the Object Reference of an StringBuilder Object with MDLC (the Magic is Clearing it before add the content):

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder booleans = new StringBuilder();

    using (NestedDiagnosticsContext.Push(Guid.NewGuid()))
    using (MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("xml", xml))
    using (MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("numbers", numbers))
    using (MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("booleans", booleans)) 
    {
        try {

            logger.Info("Before XML change");

            xml.Clear().Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>..");
            numbers.Clear().Append(20);
            logger.Info("After XML change");
            booleans.Clear().Append(true);
            logger.Info("After Boolean change");
            numbers.Clear().Append(100);
            logger.Info("After number change");
            xml.Clear().Append("no xml anymore");
            logger.Info("After XML change");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "ow noos!");
            throw;
        }
    }
    logger.Info("After using");
}
```

Of course i would be impractically for return values because you would have to convert it back, but for most times i is a good solution and a little more readable than setting the MDLC again.

Best regards
Lord_Pinhead

Comment: Lots of code examples, but no real description of what output is expected, and the actual result. But yes `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped` doesn't restore any original value on dispose. It just removes the active value. I guess you could make a PullRequest with a special SetScoped that can check for original value first (and restore it on dispose).

Comment: Sorry, i was a little bit unclear about that. When i set the MDLC Parameter, it is an variable by value, not reference. When i update the variable, i have to set it again for the new value. I just would  like to know, if there is something i could use to set a reference instead of the value. So after an Update of the variable, the value in the MDLC will update too. There is no way of setting it over an Pointer or Ref Keyword. A Pullrequest in GH is something i thought about yesterday, but i dont want to reinvent the weel if there is a way.

Comment: Ahh now I understand. You want to modify the existing string-value in the MDLC. .NET Framework string-objects are Immutable and cannot be modified. You can consider using a StringBuilder (Will behave like your DataClass).

Comment: That is the easiest solution for it. I totally forgot that variables are immutable, so even a reference whould be futile. Thanks for the tip, make it an normal answer so i can flag it as the solution. I update my question with a working code example doing exactly what i want.

Comment: Just a curious question. If SetScoped behaved differently, so it actually restored any previous value on dispose. Then I guess that would also solve your issue? (As you could just call SetScoped when wanting to modify the value)

Comment: No, the value should just be in the using part. It is right that it will be disposed on the end of the method, because it is the return value of the decorated class and in this example there is just one. When i have multiple values i have to log, the updateding could get out of hand and make the method body hard to read. And logging 10 or 20 variables in every logger.XXX() call would really hard to read. Maybe, when i have half an hour time this evening, i just wrap up an testproject, maybe it is better that way to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped` doesn't restore any original value on dispose. It just removes the active value on dispose.

NET Framework string-objects are Immutable and cannot be modified. You can consider using a StringBuilder (Will behave like your DataClass).